# JSF programmatically component in Primefaces Tab

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I created some programmatily component in a `Primefaces` Tab.

```
<h:form>
<p:tabView id="documentDetailsTabs" dynamic="true" cache="true"   >  

    <p:tab id="contenutoTab" title="#{msg['content']}" >
        <p:panelGrid  columns="4" style="width:100%"
               styleClass="table-4col-noborder"  
               binding="#{documentContentController.propertiesGridComponentModify}"
               columnClasses="label-col-4col, value-col-4col,label-col-4col, value-  col4col">  

</p:panelGrid>

    <p:commandButton value="Save" 
                    styleClass="buttonStyle"
                    process="@form"  

                    action="#{documentContentController.checkInAction}"
                    />          
    </p:tab>
</p:tabView>
</h:form>
```

The form data aren't setted in backing bean of components. If I move the `p:panelGrid` component out of the `p:tabView` the code works.

I'm using Primefaces 3.2 and  JSF 2.1.
Can you help me, please?

Comment: I'm sorry, but what is not working?

Comment: Which data is supposed to be set?

Comment: A backing bean's method set in #{documentContentController.propertiesGridComponentModify} a list of UIComponent. The backing bean of UIComponent aren't setted.