# JQuery Tab with Primefaces

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I use Primefaces 3.2, I want to use JQuery's Tab in page. In `<head>` tag I have include JQuery:

```
<h:outputScript library="js" name="jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js" />
```

In page with tab I have include this code:

```
<script>
  jQuery(function() {
    jQuery( "#tabs" ).tabs();
  });
 </script>
```

The code doesn't works. The Firebug console shows this message:

> jQuery(...).tabs is not a function

Can you help me, please?

Comment: why would you want to use JQuery Tabs when have TabView in Primefaces ?

Comment: #tabs is the <div> structure id of tab. I have this problem with Primefaces tab: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18570252/jsf-programmatically-component-in-primefaces-tab?noredirect=1#comment27332772_18570252.